# OS_Access_Violation

Tags: python, input, checkmarx

I am taking filename in put from environment variable for my python app and when I ran checkmarx validation tool I am seeing that we can not and should not pass unvalidated user input to os module.

I have added how I am getting value from user and how I am using it in os module. I know the issue can arise as user might input some malicious code as environment variable which end up hijacking the app.

```
import os
fname = os.environ.get('slink_path', /tmp/app_1.log)
symlink_name='/tmp/app.log'
os.symlink(fname, symlink_name)
```

The user-provided input from `fname` in `server.py` in line 208 is used by the file operation symlink_name in `manager.py` in line 74 without validation.

Does anyone have any idea what type of validation can/should be performed here to make app more secure. Is there any way to avoid this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a true-positive result given that it is generally a bad idea to allow an unknown user to specify values passed to OS operations.  In this case, it could be something simple like your program is running as a user that symlinks to a file that an attacker can't normally see.  There are all sorts of fun things an attacker can use this for when combined with other found vulnerabilities.

Understanding the risk, the query (my version is 9.5, this may be different in your version) is considering sanitizers as one of the following methods found in an `if` statement:

- abspath
- startswith
- lexists
- exists
- isabs
- isfile
- isdir
- realpath

Without knowing a lot about the purpose of your code, it does appear you're attempting to make a link to a log file.  This code will sanitize the result, but you may want to add some more restrictive checking criteria:

```
import os
fname = os.environ.get('slink_path', /tmp/app_1.log)

if isfile(fname):
    symlink_name='/tmp/app.log'
    os.symlink(fname, symlink_name)
```